# Correct scenario for lost update issue

Tags: hibernate, transactions

This is the description for lost update problem from Java Persistence With Hibernate

> A lost update occurs if two transactions both update a row and then the second
>   transaction aborts, causing both changes to be lost. This occurs in systems that
>   don’t implement locking. The concurrent transactions aren’t isolated.

T1 -> 1. update D1 -> 3. commit

T2 -> 2. update D1 -> 4. Rollback. //numbers designate the sequence of operation.

Here my first problem is how the changes committed by T1 will be lost with the rollback done by T2?

Second question is, I browse alot for lost update problem every where the description I got matches with second lost update problem described in the same book.

T1 -> 1. Select D1 -> 3. update D1 -> 4. commit

T2 -> 2. Select D1 -> 5. update D1 -> 6. commit

here the changes made by T1 are overwritten by the commit of T2.

Which is the correct scenario for lost update?
If we consider the first scenario then how its possible to rollback the changes committed by transaction 1?

Comment: I think that, if we replace step 4 for a *commit* in the first scenario, it becomes a **lost update** problem. As far I know, in this problems doesn't matters what happens to the affected data/row before the update statements, so the second scenario fit but select statements abound.

The second scenario looks like more an **unrepeatable read** situation. It shows that one transaction could be doing changes based on previous retrieved data that was modified by other transaction in the meanwhile; I mean that the first transaction is using stale data to make changes.

Comment: @Guillermo but its not possible to update same row at a same time

Comment: I don't understand your comment... It is not necessary update same row at a same nick of time to get a lost update problem but reproduce the sql commands order (leaving aside the undelaring transactions isolation behaivor)